# SQL Table Partition Giving Alter Table Error

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have a database table having million of records. In order to optimize the query I want to partition my table on the basis of state (i.e. America).
But when i execute the alter table code in sql section is prompt me error.

I have partitioned my table on the basis of "ST" column.

```
ALTER TABLE data_managements PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS (ST)
(
PARTITION AL VALUES IN ('AL'),
PARTITION AK VALUES IN ('AK'),
PARTITION AZ VALUES IN ('AZ'),
PARTITION AR VALUES IN ('AR'),
PARTITION CA VALUES IN ('CA'),
PARTITION CO VALUES IN ('CO'),
PARTITION CT VALUES IN ('CT'),
PARTITION DE VALUES IN ('DE'),
PARTITION FL VALUES IN ('FL'),
PARTITION GA VALUES IN ('GA'),
PARTITION HI VALUES IN ('HI'),
PARTITION ID VALUES IN ('ID'),
PARTITION IL VALUES IN ('IL'),
PARTITION `IN` VALUES IN ('IN'),
PARTITION IA VALUES IN ('IA'),
PARTITION KS VALUES IN ('KS'),
PARTITION KY VALUES IN ('KY'),
PARTITION LA VALUES IN ('LA'),
PARTITION ME VALUES IN ('ME'),
PARTITION MD VALUES IN ('MD'),
PARTITION MA VALUES IN ('MA'),
PARTITION MI VALUES IN ('MI'),
PARTITION MN VALUES IN ('MN'),
PARTITION MS VALUES IN ('MS'),
PARTITION MO VALUES IN ('MO'),
PARTITION MT VALUES IN ('MT'),
PARTITION NE VALUES IN ('NE'),
PARTITION NV VALUES IN ('NV'),
PARTITION NH VALUES IN ('NH'),
PARTITION NJ VALUES IN ('NJ'),
PARTITION NM VALUES IN ('NM'),
PARTITION NY VALUES IN ('NY'),
PARTITION NC VALUES IN ('NC'),
PARTITION ND VALUES IN ('ND'),
PARTITION OH VALUES IN ('OH'),
PARTITION OK VALUES IN ('OK'),
PARTITION `OR` VALUES IN ('OR'),
PARTITION PA VALUES IN ('PA'),
PARTITION RI VALUES IN ('RI'),
PARTITION SC VALUES IN ('SC'),
PARTITION SD VALUES IN ('SD'),
PARTITION TN VALUES IN ('TN'),
PARTITION TX VALUES IN ('TX'),
PARTITION UT VALUES IN ('UT'),
PARTITION VT VALUES IN ('VT'),
PARTITION VA VALUES IN ('VA'),
PARTITION WA VALUES IN ('WA'),
PARTITION WV VALUES IN ('WV'),
PARTITION WI VALUES IN ('WI'),
PARTITION WY VALUES IN ('WY')
);
```

The system should create above mentioned partitions as per requirements but it prompt me two errors:

```
* Missing comma before start of a new alter operation. (near "PARTITION" at position 64)
* Unrecognized alter operation. (near "PARTITION" at position 64)
```

I would appreciate if anyone could guide me to sort this thing out.
Thanks,

Comment: Sounds to me like the error may be from something happening before this statement

Comment: there is nothing before it, i can't figure it out where i gone wrong.